# How to show 3 images in the FlipView with DataBinding

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I have a flip view and 3 images,I want it to change images automatically,the problem is that I used the Binding technique but it does not work,I get white images in my flipView,this is my code:

MyPage.cs:

```
 private void AddImageIntoList()
        {
            var page1 = new SampleItem()
            {
                Image1 = "images/img1.jpg", 
            };

            var page2 = new SampleItem()
            {
                Image2 = "images/img2.jpg",
            };

            var page3 = new SampleItem()
            {
                Image3 = "images/img3.jpg",
            };

            var pages = new List<SampleItem>()
            {
                page1,
                page2,
                page3
            };

            flipView1.ItemsSource = pages;
            ContextControl.ItemsSource = pages;
            ContextControl.SelectionChanged += ContextControl_SelectionChanged;
        }}
```

MyPage.xaml.cs:

```
 <FlipView  x:Name="flipView1" Background="Transparent" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False">
            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="{Binding}" />
                        </Grid.Background>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

ButtonImages.cs:

```
public class SampleItem
        {

        public string Image1 { get; set; }
        public string Image2 { get; set; }
        public string Image3 { get; set; }
    }

    public class ButtonImages
    {
        public List<SampleItem> SampleItems { get; set; }

            public ButtonImages()
            {
                SampleItems = new List<SampleItem>();

                SampleItems.Add(new SampleItem()
                {
                    Image1 = "images/img1.jpg"
                });

                SampleItems.Add(new SampleItem()
                {
                    Image2 = "images/img2.jpg"
                });

            SampleItems.Add(new SampleItem()
            {
                Image3 = "images/img3.jpg"
            });
```

}

so please how can I correct my code to show those 3 images in the FlipView with DataBinding

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get why SampleItem class has three properties Image1-3. It should have only one property Image (or you can ignore SampleItem class and use just strings - image paths). After that, change your binding in ImageBrush to:

```
ImageSource="{Binding Image}"
```